# How to use 503 Thermistors for temperature?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a black Thermistor with the number 503 on it.

I know that I would need a 50k resistor as a voltage divider.

I don't get to convert the number I am getting. I get the number 340 when my house is at 64*F. 
I bought a kit on Amazon and it came with it and there is no documentation.A test with multimeter has shown at 17*C I get 30k ohms.

This is how it is wired:

```
[Ground] -- [50k-resistor] -- | -- [(503)thermistor] --[Vcc (5v)]
                              |
                         Analog Pin 0
```

Comment: That's what happens when you get a random component from somewhere. Find one with a datasheet.

Comment: Can you please also post the code of your sketch?

Comment: I don't what to do with the value the code is just analogRead from pin 0

Comment: A very similar question was posted in the Arduino forums a few years ago: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=4757.0

Comment: it was never answered

Comment: Have you measured the resistance of the thermistor, using a multimeter?

Comment: Ok I will measure and let you know the value

Comment: i get 30k ohms at 17*C

Comment: If you repeat that at another temperature, you can tell whether the device has a positive or negative  temperature coefficient (NTC decreases resistance with increasing temperature). That will help you identify the device and match it to a data sheet.

Comment: The rated resistance is the resistance at 25degC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some code for a 10k thermistor and modified it for a 50k and cut out the code to display Celcius.  I found this on the Arduino playground posted by: Milan Malesevic and Zoran Stupic.

Origional code is found here: http://playground.arduino.cc/ComponentLib/Thermistor2

This is what I came up with and it returned the proper temp in F for a 503 Thermistor.

```
#include <math.h>
// enumerating 3 major temperature scales
enum {
  T_KELVIN=0,
  T_CELSIUS,
  T_FAHRENHEIT
};

#define EPISCO_K164_10k 4300.0f,298.15f,50000.0f  // B,T0,R0  

float Temperature(int AnalogInputNumber,int OutputUnit,float B,float T0,float R0,float R_Balance)
{
  float R,T;

//  R=1024.0f*R_Balance/float(analogRead(AnalogInputNumber)))-R_Balance;
  R=R_Balance*(1024.0f/float(analogRead(AnalogInputNumber))-1);

  T=1.0f/(1.0f/T0+(1.0f/B)*log(R/R0));

  switch(OutputUnit) {
    case T_CELSIUS :
      T-=273.15f;
    break;
    case T_FAHRENHEIT :
      T=9.0f*(T-273.15f)/5.0f+32.0f;
    break;
    default:
    break;
  };

  return T;
}

//example of use #2
// using numbers instead of episco k164 definition
// this time reading from analog input 2
// getting result in fahrenheit

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

 Serial.println("********");
 Serial.println("Temp");
 Serial.println(Temperature(2,T_FAHRENHEIT,4300.0f,298.15f,50000.0f,10000.0f));
 Serial.println("********");
 Serial.println(" ");

 delay(500);
}
```

Good luck!!!!

Comment: I should mention that to get an accurate reading you will need to measure the 10k resistor and use its actual value in the line below. Mine measured 9.95k so below I replaced the 10000 with 9950. 
`Serial.println(Temperature(2,T_FAHRENHEIT,4300.0f,298.15f,50000.0f,9950.0f));`

Answer (score 1):

First of, **503** means 50 x 10^3, ie **50K Ohm**: that is the maximum resistance of this thermistor (the higher resistance occurs for lower temperatures). However, having just that without any precise reference may prove difficult to find a relevant datasheet that could help you calculate the temperature from the measured voltage.

I think what could work well is just simple calibration by establishing a mapping between
the value returned by `analogRead()` and the temperature measured by a real, good precision, thermometer.

Establighing the mapping for 2 extreme temperatures would provide a **first approximation** on computing any temperature from the read value.

However, such an approximation would not be very accurate because thermistors are **not linear**, ie their resitance don't vary linearly with temperature.

What you can try to do then, is to increase the number of mapped *value<->temperature* with regular intervals of temperatures; then you can use linear approximation between two consecutive mapped values, which would provide better results.

The difficulty here is to "produce" the temperatures for which you want to find the mapped value: if you can spend one year for that, then just let the chqanging seasons operate that for you :-) otherwise use what you can find at home: fridge, oven, fan, heater...

Answer (score -1):

Here is a [link to Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/1127-ntc-503-r-negative-temperature-coefficient-ntc-thermistor.html), one supplier of a 503 thermistor - it is a negative-coefficient thermistor. They have a link to a data-sheet for it. I can't say for sure that this is your device, but a simple experiment with your ohm-meter should confirm it.

Comment: If the anonymous downvoter would care to comment on what s/he thinks is inadequate about this answer, I'd like to know. Maybe someone - me included - would benefit from it.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer for a reason that seemed obvious to me: you are just posting a link to a datasheet, which you can even not for sure say that it is relevant for the OP. That does not answer the original question!

Comment: I just think that a commentto the question would have been enough. Orherwise, a further development on how to use the datasheet in the OP context would be needed.